# Easier way to revert commit

Tags: git, version-control

I have repo with such history:

```
H
|
C
|
M
|\
| X
| |
| B
| |
| A
|/
R
```

Now I need to revert X commit. Problem - there are many commits hidden under M-C-H, some files need to be totally rewritten. Is there any trick to simplify this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `git rebase -i` to delete the commit X, and then subsequent ones will be rebased automatically.

So if `xxx` is the SHA for commit X, run:

```
git rebase -i xxx^
```

and then edit the file to delete (or comment) the line that says xxx

```
pick xxx This is the X commit < delete this line
pick mmm This is the M commit
pick ccc This is the C commit
pick hhh This is the H commit
```

Once you save the file then it will perform the rewriting. If there are conflicts introduced by doing this, you'll need to resolve them manually, perform `git add` on the conflicted file, and when all are done, `git rebase --continue`

Comment: Isn't rebase just moves changes, not removes them?

Comment: If you delete the line then it will remove the commit. Similarly you can reorder them or squash them.